# How to Convert Int Value into Hours (time) from mssql to EJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, datetime, ejs

I am currently working on a project where I have to received the data from SQL Server and render that data into a webpage (EJS) using node.js. 
Below give image is an outcome of my data.

[image]

Now I wanted to convert the LengthTime (Which is in Int format in MSSQL database) into Hours format and I wanted to show StartTime and Entime like "11/12/2018 12:02:04 PM". How can I do that?

My Coding for SQL and EJS.

```js
function receiveData(req, res)
{
    db.executeSql("SELECT Machine,StartTime,EndTime,LengthTime,Day,JobNumber FROM Arduino order by StartTime DESC", function (recordsets, err, ) {

        var data = JSON.stringify(recordsets);

        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(request, res, err);
        }
        else {

          var    Jdata = JSON.parse(data);


            console.log(Jdata);


            res.render('arduino',{Jdata:Jdata});



        }
    });
}
```

```html
        <center> <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">
            <tr>
                <th> ID </th>
                <th>-</th>
                <th>Machine</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Length Time</th>
                <th> Day/Night</th>
                <th>Job Number</th>
            </tr>
            <% if(Jdata.recordset.length){

            for(var i = 0;i < Jdata.recordset.length;i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=(i+1)%></td>
                <td> </td>
                <td><%=Jdata.recordset[i].Machine %></td>
                <td><%=Jdata.recordset[i].StartTime%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata.recordset[i].EndTime%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata.recordset[i].LengthTime%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata.recordset[i].Day%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata.recordset[i].JobNumber%></td>

            </tr>
            <% }

            }else{ %>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">No Data</td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>

        </table> </center>
```

Comment: Do you want an answer for SQL Server?

Comment: @Sami, Thanks for your Reply, I wanted to display it into the web page..

Answer (score 0):

Since the `LengthTime`is always < `86400` you can do like

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(Second, LengthTime, 0), 108) AS TIME)
FROM YourTable;
```

You can create a view, or in your query write

```
db.executeSql("SELECT Machine,StartTime,EndTime,CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(Second, LengthTime, 0), 108) AS TIME) LengthTime ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting an output like "1970-01-01T00:00:38.000Z", But i wanted to get the output in hours format. For example: "01:30.40". Is there anyway format like that. Thanks